# Is localStorage reliable on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, local-storage, offline

I'm seeing a few comments from people suggesting that localStorage on an iPad is unreliable.  Can anyone confirm that they are happily using localStorage on an iPad?  I understand that there is a 5Mb limit too - is that still the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been working on a project that uses localStorage on an iPad. In my experience, the localStorage is perfectly stable. However, there are two things to consider:

- Yes, the storage-limit is still 5Mb. Since characters are stored UTF16, only 2.5M characters can be stored in localStorage.
- In contrast to other localStorage implementations, localStorage.setItem() doesn't delete any previous items with the same key before storing the new item. In other words: When overwriting an item, one should always call localStorage.removeItem() before calling localStorage.setItem(), or you'll quickly run out of space.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re removeItem