# Temporarily storing data on iPad without WiFi

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi, store

I am developing an application where the user will not have WiFi and needs to save their data until they have WiFi and then upload their data. Is there any temporary uploading programs I could use?

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults for small amount of data or Core Data if you have more. Pls see my answer related to NSUserDefaults: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475300/storing-results-after-screen-is-disappear/16476022#16476022

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the localStorage? It's becoming more reliable. I've used it in my own applications and the API is easy enough to pick up.

When using it with the iPad TumbleCow has one or two things to keep in mind.

> 1. Yes, the storage-limit is still 5Mb. Since characters are stored UTF16, only 2.5M characters can be stored in localStorage.
> 2. In contrast to other localStorage implementations, localStorage.setItem() doesn't delete any previous items with the same key before storing the new item. In other words: When overwriting an item, one should always call localStorage.removeItem() before calling localStorage.setItem(), or you'll quickly run out of space.

[Is localStorage reliable on an iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887326/is-localstorage-reliable-on-an-ipad)